# SwiftUI causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS & stack trace with none of my calls in it

Tags: swiftui

Just spend hours searching for a bug in my SwiftUI Code...

All I got was an endless stack trace with none of my calls in it and `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at the end.

I had no clue what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

**If this happens to you - first check if you have a "`.`" in front of all your view modifiers!!**

It seems that in some cases it compiles without the "`.`" and XCode shows correct syntax highlighting. It took forever to spot it...

In my case it was `.onLongPressGesture` instead of `onLongPressGesture`

I tried to figure out why this happens (it does not seem to happen in all of my views) - so if anyone could shine some light on this.. I'd appreciate to know!